# Galois Cohomology (doubt in greenberg's paper)

Tags: galois-representations, galois-cohomology

I'm reading the paper "Iwasawa Theory for p-adic representation" in which I am not unable to follow one statement:

Let $K \subset \overline {\mathbb Q} $ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$. Let $V_p$ be a representation space over $\mathbb Q_p$ for $G_K=Gal(\overline K/K)$ of dimension d, $T_p$  a  $G_K$-invariant lattice, and $A=V_P/T_p \cong (\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p)^d.$ Let $Ram(V_p)$ denote the set of places of $K$ which are ramified in $K(A)/K$. Assume that $Ram(V_p)$ is finite. Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing $Ram(V_p)$, all places over $p$, and all infinite places. Let $K_s$ denote the maximal extension of $K$ unramified outside $S$.

Question: Why A is a $Gal(K_S/K)$ module?

Comment: Since $V_p$ and $T_p$ are unramified at the primes in $S$, $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline K/K_S)$ acts trivially on $V_p$ and $T_p$.

Comment: $V_p$ and $T_p$ are may ramified at the primes in S. sorry, there was a typo. @Mathmo123

Comment: What is $K(A)$? But, if $\nu \not \in S$ implies that 'the' corresponding inertia group $I$ [defined up to conjugation] acts trivially on $T_p$ and $V_p$, @Mathmo123's answer is right: $Gal (\overline K/ K_S)$ is generated by such $I$.

Comment: I'm also guilty of a typo! I meant that $V_p$ and $T_p$ are unramified outside $S$